# Rake Aborted due to invalid sequence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake, rvm

I am updating one of rails app on my server with new content. It was working fine until the previous day. Now when I try to migrate my db using rake or use any rake commands, I get the following errors:

```
rake aborted!
rake aborted!
invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:16:in `block in trace_on'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:14:in `map'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/trace_output.rb:14:in `trace_on'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:328:in `trace'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:183:in `display_error_message'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:169:in `rescue in standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:159:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My local machine ruby version is: 2.0.0p0
And my server ruby version is: ruby 1.9.3p194

Is it because I need to update my ruby version on my server to 2.0.0p0

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is one of the changes between ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0.0 - default utf-8 encoding, you should always try to develop, test and deploy on the same version of ruby (you can/should test on more rubies).

Comment: Okay I will update my ruby version n the server and try this.
Thank You

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

to the top of your migration file.

Comment: I am not able to run any of the rake tasks viz., rake routes, rake db:reset, rake db:create etc.

Comment: @swaroopsm did you make changes in any of your initializers/environment files? Especially did you insert special characters to one of these?

Comment: No I did not do any changes. I just added some data to be inserted in seeds.rb, and a rake task to populate other tables

Comment: Paste the contents of this rake task.

Answer (score 1):

Add a system environment in the

```
~/.bash_profile file.
export RUBYOPT='-KU'
```

in my host ,it works well.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked quite nicely for me.  (The problem I had was that rake db:reset had suddenly stopped working, giving the error described by the OP).